# C++ ffmpeg get the current frame

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decode

I'm trying to seek to a certain part of a video using ffmpeg. So far I've got this:

```cpp
int64_t pts = (int64_t)( ((float) timestamp_to_go / 1000)* (double)time_base.den / (double)time_base.num);
if(av_seek_frame(av_format_ctx, video_stream_index, pts, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD) < 0 )
    exit(0);
```

This allows me to seek to the closest IFrame. For example if I try to seek to the 10th second of a video, it seeks to the 8.5th second of a video. This is fine since I can just decode till I reach the 10th seconds and go on with my day.

However I couldn't figure out how to get the current frame index. After I seek to the frame using the code above, I need to figure out which frame/timestamp I'm currently at so I can decode until I reach the timestamp desired.

For example: If I try to seek to 10 and get 8.5 like example above, for a video with 30 fps I need to get `255` so I can decode untill I reach the 300th frame, which corresponds to the 10th second.

Comment: Don't tag a C++ question with the C tag unless you are particularly fond of downvotes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's both c and c++, actually it's more on the c side since ffmpeg's library is written in c. My bad for writing the title like that tho.

Comment: Then don't put C++ (or, worse, C/C++) in the title.  But choose either C or C++; don’t tag with both languages unless you are asking about the interworking of the two languages in some respect.